# C# Regex to replace invalid character to make it as perfect float number

Tags: c#, regex

for example if the string is "-234.24234.-23423.344"
the result should be "-234.2423423423344"

if the string is "898.4.44.4"
the result should be "898.4444"

if the string is "-898.4.-"
the result should be "-898.4"

the result should always make scene as a double type

What I can make is this:

```
string pattern = String.Format(@"[^\d\{0}\{1}]", 
NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.NumberDecimalSeparator, 
NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.NegativeSign);

string result = Regex.Replace(value, pattern, string.Empty); 
// this will not be able to deal with something like this "-.3-46821721.114.4"
```

Is there any perfect way to deal with those cases?

Comment: Where would you get such nonsensical input, and why do you want to treat it as valid in the first place?

Comment: It sounds like you only want to keep one sign and one decimal separator. That's doable *without* regular expressions, which you prematurely seem to think is the solution to this. But how can you be sure that gives you relevant results, given the crappy level of the input?

Comment: it is used for masktextbox, to prevent user paste nonsensical input.

Comment: @tianxu0836, you are not preventing anything. You are trying to recover gracefully without knowing whether that's even possible. Save yourself the head-ache and only accept legible input instead.

Comment: I second bzlm, if you want to prevent nonsensical input then just check if the user input is a proper decimal, don't try to assume what they typed when it was nonsensical to begin with.

Comment: @tianxu0836 If you're using the Regex as a textbox mask like your comment says, then you don't need to replace invalid characters because they won't occur in the masked text box, and you don't need to ask a question about replacement. Instead, what you need to ask for is a Regex pattern to use as a mask that will allow only valid floating point input.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably a bad idea, but you can do this with regex like this:

```
Regex.Replace(input, @"[^-.0-9]|(?<!^)-|(?<=\..*)\.", "")
```

The regex matches:

```
[^-.0-9]    # anything which isn't ., -, or a digit.
|           # or
(?<!^)-     # a - which is not at the start of the string
|           # or
(?<=\..*)\. # a dot which is not the first dot in the string
```

This works on your examples, and additionally this case: "9-1.1" becomes "91.1".

You could also change `(?<!^)-` to `(?<!^[^-.0-9]*)-` if you'd like "asd-8" to become "-8" rather than "8".

Comment: WOW, 10 years after the answer and it worked perfectly for me! Thanks. Now I'm curious why you said it's a bad idea)

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good idea using regex itself to achieve your goal, since regex lack `AND` and `NOT` logic for expression.

Try the code below, it will do the same thing.

```
var str = @"-.3-46821721.114.4";
var beforeHead = "";
var afterHead = "";

var validHead = new Regex(@"(\d\.)" /* use @"\." if you think "-.5" is also valid*/, RegexOptions.Compiled);
Regex.Replace(str, @"[^0-9\.-]", "");
var match = validHead.Match(str);

beforeHead = str.Substring(0, str.IndexOf(match.Value));
if (beforeHead[0] == '-')
{
    beforeHead = '-' + Regex.Replace(beforeHead, @"[^0-9]", "");
}
else
{
    beforeHead = Regex.Replace(beforeHead, @"[^0-9]", "");
}
afterHead = Regex.Replace(str.Substring(beforeHead.Length + 2 /* 1, if you use \. as head*/), @"[^0-9]", "");

var validFloatNumber = beforeHead + match.Value + afterHead;
```

String must be trimmed before operation.